# Drawables Error: Unsupported node 'item'

Tags: android

Gradle build is giving me an error

```
Error:Error: Unsupported node 'item'
```

file name where I am getting the error

```
​app\src\main\res\values\drawables.xml
```

My drawables.xml file code

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item name="ic_menu_camera" parentType="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
<item name="ic_menu_gallery" parentType="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
<item name="ic_menu_slideshow" parentType="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
<item name="ic_menu_manage" parentType="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
<item name="ic_menu_share" parentType="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
<item name="ic_menu_send" parentType="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
 </resources>
```

This was working fine earlier. I did not make any change in this file recently and it started failing. So I think the issue is somewhere else.

How do I troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Have you tried changing parentType to type?

Comment: Thank you. That worked. How do I select your comment as the answer?

Comment: I think you cannot mark comments as answers but I posted my answer below so that you can mark it, and maybe others can benefit from it. I'm glad that helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing **parentType** to **type**. parentType is not a supported keyword, but type is.